# Seeking URL() replacement for deprecated parse() in Next.js createServer()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

The method for creating a custom server for Next.js is provided in the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server):

```
// server.js
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/a') {
      app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
    } else if (pathname === '/b') {
      app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
})
```

However, `parse()` is now flagged as deprecated. The official replacement for `parse` is the [WHATWG URL api](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_constructor_new_url_input_base).

But the `URL` class object is not usable by `handle()` function within the `createServer()` function (i.e., the `parsedUrl` object created using `parse(req.url, true)` cannot be used by `handle(req, res, parsedUrl)`).

How can the code above be rewritten to use the `URL` api instead of `parse`? (Or is there a different solution without either `URL` or `parse`?)

Comment: @brc-dd I'd already read the other SO post you reference, and the responders there do not understand the author's issue, which the author attempts to clarify in a response. The real issue is that server will break because `handle()` expects a different object type than the one `URL()` creates; the mapping between UrlWithParsedQuery and the URL object is different enough to break the routine.

Comment: Did you figured it out? Quite surprising not to find a quick solution for this yet!